# How to get glm-like odds ratios from xgboost?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, xgboost

I have successfully run a machine learning algorithm usuing xgboost on Python 3.8.5, but am struggling with interpretation of the results.

the output/target is binary, deceased or not deceased.

Both myself and my audience understand odds ratios like what come from R's `glm` well, and I'm sure that xgboost can display this information somehow, but I can't figure out how.

My first instinct is to look at the output from `xgboost`'s `predict_proba`

but when I do that, I get

```
>>> deceased.pp.view()
array([[0.5828363 , 0.4171637 ],
       [0.89795643, 0.10204358],
       [0.5828363 , 0.4171637 ],
       [0.89795643, 0.10204358]], dtype=float32)
```

I'm *assuming* that these are the p that would go into the formula 1/(1-p) to calculate an odds ratio for each input term like `sex` and `age`.

I found a similar question on this website but the answer doesn't help me:

[xgboost predict_proba : How to do the mapping between the probabilities and the labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420610/xgboost-predict-proba-how-to-do-the-mapping-between-the-probabilities-and-the)

so based on the answer there, I use the `.classes_` to get this

```
>>> deceased.xg_clf.classes_
array([False,  True])
```

In fact, I'm not even sure that xgboost *can* give glm-like odds ratios, the closest thing seems to be feature_importances.

However, feature importance doesn't give the same information that odds ratios do.

but `.classes_` tells me nothing about how to find out which input categories, e.g. `age` or `sex` have what probabilities.

How can I link `classes_` with the input categories?
Or if that is not correct or impossible, how else can I calculate odds ratios ***for each input variable*** in xgboost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed that it doesn't really fit for XGBoost to provide something like an odds ratio. Have you taken a look at other forms of model interpretability for more complex models like XGBoost? [`shap`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap), for example, is a library that can provide similar sorts of analysis but is more well-suited for these types of models.

Answer (score 0):

> how else can I calculate odds ratios for each input variable in xgboost?

Regarding this question: I have a solution for **binary** explanatory variables.

I am new to this forum, so please feel free to correct my answer if I'm wrong. If you want to display coefficients in an XGBoost model, [DoubleML](https://docs.doubleml.org/stable/index.html) is a package available for both R and Python. The package is built on the results from [Chernozhukov et al. (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1111/ectj.12097) for analyzing effects from explanatory variables in ML models.

You can use the DoubleMLIRM model from the package to explain what the paper describes as Average Treatment Effects (Chapter 5 of the paper):

**θ<sub>0</sub> = [g<sub>0</sub>(1,X) - g(0,X)]**

Where **θ**, as they state, is the average treatment effect. In other words: the effect of a binary explanatory variable, on the dependent variable.

**g<sub>0</sub>(1,X)** describes that the dependent variable depends on control variables **X**, and the binary explanatory variable of interest **D={1,0}**. But **g<sub>0</sub>** does not assume the functional form. Hence, you can apply XGBoost.

The nice thing about this model is that you are provided with confidence intervals, such that you are able to conduct inference on the coefficient values.